# How do i set a string and value in Registry?

Tags: windows, registry

Sorry, it is a very basic cuestion,
 I want to add a program with a reg script to startup list, in this registry :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

like this :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run Add "Myprogram".
```

Any suggestion, i dont wont to do it manually, i have to use a script or batch file.

Comment: You know that registry manipulation requires some special prerequisites like uac answering and so on. Which windows version is targeted and what privileges are available?

Comment: THanks, i know, then is it not possible? Well..

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516

Comment: It is possible. In our company we do it many times, but we are then logged in as admin.

Comment: I ask you, please not to intervene in this thread again if you wanna mock my intellegence. Im asking for help, cause i tried, scripting batch and registry logged as an ADMIN, that is logic.

Comment: I did not want to mock anything. I just wanted to know, what You tried, where Your standing was and where exactly to start in order to give  You proper hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"BIOSPath"= REG_SZ:F:\BiosUpdaterPL.exe
```